# Working on railstutorial.org Ch 10. Cannot delete users through browser as admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, railstutorial.org

In chapter 10 of railstutorial.org, I cannot delete users through the browser. All tests pass, including user deletion tests, but when attempting to delete a user as an admin through the browser pointed to localhost:3000, I am merely directed to the user's profile.

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

Is the code used to generate the deletion link.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

has been included in the headers.

I'm really stumped as to why this is happening. The logs for the server show a GET request for the user's info, as one would expect when being directed to the user page rather than destroying the user.

Also, using `button_to` instead of `link_to` will delete a user, but won't confirm the action.

EDIT: Adding routes.rb by request

```
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]

resources :users

match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'  
match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
match '/signin', :to => 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

root :to => 'pages#home'

get "pages/home"
get "pages/contact"
get "pages/about"
get "pages/help"
```

EDIT: application.js added by request

```
require jquery
require jquery_ujs
require_tree .
```

EDIT: users_controller.rb added by request

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user, :only => :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign Up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    UserMailer.pw_email(@user).deliver
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign Up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @title = "Edit User"
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit User"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @title = "All Users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

Comment: do you have js disabled? Perhaps you are missing jquery-ujs?

Comment: @stephenmurdoch I don't believe js is disabled. I have no idea about jquery-ujs I've tried using both `javascript_include_tag :defaults` and `javascript_include_tag :all` in the headers.

Comment: Can you post your `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: Yeah, it's difficult to tell without seeing some code. I have several questions. Which rails version of rails is the app running on? Which version of rails was the app generated with? Are you using the asset pipeline? Are you using jquery-rails gem? What is the content of your application.js file?

Comment: Can you post your `UserController` too please

Comment: @AlexPeattie How can I post the user controller without typing in 4 spaces in front of each line, because that just plain isn't happening.

Comment: Hit the button that looks like { } (or just wrap the code in `<pre><code>` and `</pre></code>`

Comment: @stephenmurdoch application.js posted.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch Sorry, working on and created with rails 3.1 and the jquery-rails gem is listed in the gemfile and installed. I don't understand your question about the asset pipeline.

Comment: see dylan markows answer below

Comment: @stephenmurdoch That didn't change anything.

Comment: hmm, odd. Can you paste code on github? It might be easier to see what's wrong there. Also, rememeber to remove any S3 credentials or sensitive stuff before you push

Comment: @stephenmurdoch sorry, no. I've gone into customizing things like titles and passwords and I'm not sure where all of them are anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As of Rails 3.1, you need to be using `application`, not `defaults` or `all`, otherwise your `application.js` manifest file never gets loaded, which means jQuery never gets loaded.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

Comment: When you view your page source, do you see multiple javascript lines including paths like `/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your template:

```
# note that this is plural
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Read more about it [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper/csrf_meta_tags):